# extract data from webservice ?WSDL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

my teacher gave me a url to a webservice of my school with the purpose of extracting some data to help me with a project im making. the thing is he doesnt want to tell me how i am supposed to extract the data from it. i know it has a lot of operations/methods or whatever it's called and i know it has something to do with xml. im doing a website in asp.net and c#.

i've been searching for some code but i dont really understand it.

```
NameoftheService.Service myservice = new NameofTheService.Service();
```

and to call the method/operation (example):

```
var abc = myservice.GetWeather(parameter);
```

but i cant get this thing to work. i've replaced the code above with correct information but it says could not execute query. i dont really know what to do

Comment: You have to add web reference(Service Reference) to your project. To add web reference right click on References and add service reference then enter your WSDL url to add service reference.

Comment: i did that today and still didnt manage to make it work

Comment: If possible Share your wdsl url, So I can guide you.

Comment: http://esb-srv.aseb.pt:11001/asebApp_WS/RH_WebServiceService?WSDL

this is the url. but it's local. you can only access if you're in the school's intranet so i dont really know if it helps

Comment: So, After adding web reference, what you are getting. You have to call it by creating instance. like `ServiceNameSpace.ServiceClass obj = new  ServiceNameSpace.ServiceClass(); obj.MethodName();`

Comment: ok so what if i wanted to fill a grid with information from that method?

Comment: Do you want it in windows application, web form or MVC?

Comment: i want it in web form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind grid in asp.net is as simple as binding it with object list. Consider the product service. So your code should be like...

```
ProductsService.DataSetWebService ws = new ProductsService.DataSetWebService();  
GridView1.DataSource = ws.GetProducts();  
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the properties of NameOfTheService.Service will be a DestinationURL or ServiceURL that you need to set.

Comment: i already added the service reference in my solution. is it needed anyways?